# Java, FTP And Multiple Consumers

Tags: java, design-patterns, ftp, ftp-client, spring-jms

is there any way with FTPClient to get the number of simultaneous connections that a particular ftp server will allow? And also the number of available connections at any time?

My problem is as follows
I have a queue at the minute that a consumer will read data from and create a file. At the moment there are 3 consumers (Spring JMS concurrent consumers) for the queue but this  number will increase and more servers listening to the queue will be added.

When I update the consumers to be 100, i get errors that the connections will fail.
Can anyone recommend a design pattern or a library that will allow any number of consumers to ftp to a particular server. If for example there are 100 files and 100 consumers, if each consumer could ftp 1 file or some could ftp 10 files etc etc, that would be the desired approach. I want to split the load across multiple consumers and / or servers

Any help with this is much appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can switch to SFTP, the Jsch library supports opening multiple channels over a single physical connection.

Otherwise you could implement a pool of FTP clients and block the consumer if there are no clients available. When a consumer completes its operation, return the client to the pool and wake up any waiting threads. A simple `BlockingQueue` is likely all you would need.

Most servers will time out idle connections, though, so you'd have to deal with a broken connection when getting one from the pool.

Finally, if you use Spring Integration instead of rolling your own, the FTP outbound channel adapter can be configured to use a `CachingSessionFactory`, which handles the pooling for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response gary.. I will look at Jsch thanks. The BlockingQueue would work but I dont think it would be the correct option if more than 1 server is reading from the queue

Comment: True, but you can limit the connections from each server that way.

Comment: true gary but would it be optimal? If the ftp server allowed 10 connections, could we tell in a smart way how many connections to allow from each server? Ideally a new server should be able to startup without knowing about any other servers